# Including UI in library for windows 8 phone

Tags: c#, user-interface, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I am looking to build an server authentication library.. My requirement is to create an login screen which takes user credentials as input and then grants access based on the validity of credentials..This library is to be used by windows 8 phones..

**My question is which project template do I choose in Visual Studio 2013?**(I am using visual c#)..**Second question is how is it possible to include UI in a library?**..Since i am new to wp8 i only know how to create UI using XAML..On creating windows phone class library project, it does not have xaml files or designer view to support building UI..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "Phone Class Library" and actually creating xaml files in it.

Then you can navigate to this file with uri constructed like this: `/{assemblyName};component/{pathToResource}`

{assemblyName} is the name of library that you should use when navigating to pages in different assembly

So for example if you have `SomePage.xaml` in library `SomeAssembly` you should use `"/SomeAssembly;component/SomePage.xaml"`

To check out what is your assembly name just right click on the project, click properties and find `Assembly Name`

Comment: but how to actually create a xaml file inside a phone class library?

Comment: Right click on project, then `add` then you choose what kind of xaml control you want, for example `UserControl` or `Page`, whatever suits you

Comment: Suppose I want to create a page.. how would I navigate to the page in the library from the app..Is the path in uri the same as above for a page as well?

Comment: you also may consider `ResourceDictionary`